# Does Elm have JSON Type Provider?

Tags: elm

It seems that the only way to handle JSON in Elm is to decode each JSON scheme **manually** by `Json.Decode`.

Is there a nice alternative like F#'s Type Provider or something?

[F# Data: JSON Type Provider](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html)

Comment: There is not, and for good reason I think. Your application needs very rarely map well to the JSON you consume, so the convenience you think you gain from code generation is usually lost when you have to convert the generated data structures to the application data structures. Or when you ignore the application needs by using the generated data structures directly and paint yourself into a corner. Decoders lets you go directly from JSON to the data structures your application needs, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official package doing this but there are community alternatives like this one: https://github.com/eeue56/json-to-elm

> Create Elm type aliases and decoders based on JSON input
>
> This project allows you to automate the creation of:
>
> - type aliases from JSON data
> - decoders from type aliases and some union types
> - encoders from type aliases and some union types